# Finding the nth partial sum of a series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Can someone explain how to find the nth partial sum of a series? For instance, finding the nth partial sum of the series $$\large {\frac {12}{n}- \frac {12}{n+1}}$$.

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange ! Just write a few terms and admire the beauty of what happens.

Answer (score 2):

In some of these type of questions you generally try to bring the $n^{th}$ term into the form of a difference so that on adding, the terms cancel out.

In this case, it is already of the form of a difference.

The $n^{th}$ term of the series is $\frac{12}{n}-\frac{12}{n+1}$.

$$T_n= 12\left( \frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1} \right)$$
$$T_{n-1}= 12\left( \frac{1}{n-1}-\frac{1}{n} \right)$$
$$T_{n-2}= 12\left( \frac{1}{n-2}-\frac{1}{n-1} \right)$$
$$\vdots$$
$$T_3= 12\left( \frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4} \right)$$
$$T_2= 12\left( \frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3} \right)$$
$$T_1= 12\left( \frac{1}{1}-\frac{1}{2} \right)$$

You'll notice that when you add all these together, the first term from one will cancel the second term from the term below, except the very first and very last, and hence $$S_n=12\left( 1- \frac{1}{n+1} \right)$$

Answer (score 1):

I edited your question and formatted it, which is the basic thing for math.se

So,

$T_1=12{(1-\frac{1}{2})}$

$T_2=12{(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3})}$

$T_3=12{(\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4})}$

...

$T_{(n-1)}=12{(\frac{1}{(n-1)}-\frac{1}{n})}$

$T_n=12{(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1})}$

Adding all them up will cancel out second term with the first term in the next step.

$$\large S_n=12(1-\frac{1}{(n+1)})$$